# How to edit using a WFS service, without showing it on the map in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, editing, wfs-t

I have a service with about thousand points. I wish to enable the user to edit the attributes of the features.

Since there are so many points, I don't want to display them as a vector layer (using WFS Protocol) on the map. I am using a WMS layer to display it on the map.

Using a WMSGetFeatureInfo control, I am getting the attributes of a selected point and showing them in a form to the user.

How can I now save the edited attributes to the database?  Is there some other way of achieving it?

Comment: Are you just looking for WFS-T (transactional)? Something like http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

Comment: @BradHards I am not sure that your link helps. I do know how to use a WFS-T layer; I don't want to use it in my map, because my layer has 1000's of points. If I add that layer to my map, the map becomes heavy because all the points are loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround could be to pull only the selected point as a feature in an additional layer. For instance, after the user selected a point in the WMS throuhgh the WMSGetFeatureInfo control, add a WFS-T layer that only contains the selected point, and remove it again after editing it. Then you only need o display one point at a time in a vector layer.

You can instantiate the map with a Vector layer, which has a filter, like this:

```
//selected consumers being shown as Vector (WFS) layer
saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save({auto:false});
saveStrategy.events.register('success', saveStrategy, onDataSuccesfullySaved);
saveStrategy.events.register('fail', saveStrategy, onDataSaveFail);

QueryFilter=new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "customerid",
        value: "-1"
    }),


wfslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", 
            {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),  saveStrategy],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                      url:  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Test/wfs",
                      featureType: "consumers",
                      featureNS: "http://www.example.com/Test",
                      srsName: "EPSG:4326",
                      version: "1.1.0",
                      visible:false,
                      }),
            filter:QueryFilter
            }); 
map.addLayer(wfslayer);
```

Include the following function to update the filter:

```
//function to set the wmslayer with the new filter
function SetFilter(id)
    {
        QueryFilter.value=id;
        //now Force refesh the vector layer
        wfslayer.refresh({force: true}); 
    }
```

You can change the subset, by calling the SetFilter function, with particular customerid, like this:

```
SetFilter(26570); or 

SetFilter(selId);
```

If your data is stored in a database (such as PostGIS), you could also consider writing a PHP script that updates the feature attribute table based on the feature ID you get from the WMSGetFeatureInfo request.

Comment: I followed your first suggestion. I'll edit your answer to contain the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to code it from scratch but [OpenGeo Suite's GeoExplorer](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/geoexplorer/introduction.html) supports that.

> GeoExplorer is a browser-based interface for composing and publishing
>   web-mapping applications.
>
> Using the latest version of GeoExplorer you can also style your
>   GeoServer layers and edit the data-sources underneath them.

[image]

Just [point GeoExplorer to your WMS serve](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/geoexplorer/composing.html)r, [log-in](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/geoexplorer/login.html) and then [start editing](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/geoexplorer/editing.html).

[image]

I hope that helps.