# How to stop features to redraw unwillingly in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, wfs, features

I have a problem where when editing features from a wfs vector layer. After some changes are made to the geometry, the feature redraws itself and the changes are lost.

Usually the problem occurs more often if a feature is huge and has many vertices. Also if the user pans and zooms in/out a lot.

My guess is that the browser (FireFox 18) "looses the cache" or something and therefore does a new request to the server and the feature is rendered and the changes are lost.

Is there a way to solve this or is the solution to "save often"?

Br

Mike

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35597/how-to-edit-using-a-wfs-service-without-showing-it-on-the-map-in-openlayers

Comment: Hi Mapperz and thanks for the reply

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you mean in how the answer in the other question would help me. 

I have features that are polygons. And the problem occurs when Im modifying one of them.
I could try to have a extra wfs layer only for the feature that the user currently is editing. But my guess is that won't help if that only feature is complex enough.

Or am I missing your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this happens when your vector data is retrieved using an `OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX`. A workaround would be to either use a different strategy (e.g. `OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed`), or to configure the BBOX strategy with a higher [ratio](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html#OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX.ratio).

Comment: Hi ahocevar and thank you very much for the reply and answer!
 
You are correct I'm using the BBOX strategy but by raising the ratio the problem dissapear.

I guess the down side of this is that more features than needed are retreived, but thats not an issue in this case (for now at least).

Br
Mike