# How to abort a layer event in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features, events

I have a problem ( [How to stop features to redraw unwillingly in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/how-to-stop-features-to-redraw-unwillingly-in-openlayers) ) that might be solved by aborting the beforefeatureremoved or beforefeaturesremoved event.

What I would like to to is to stop the layer from refreshing (removing and the adding again) features from a vector layer. 
If I for example make a javscript error in those methods the features isn't removed or refreshed. But causing a javascripts error causes other issues so I hope that there is a controlled way of doing this in Openlayers

I have tried the

```
layer.events.on({
   'beforefeatureremoved':function(evt){
       OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
    }
});
```

But it doesnt seem to do anything, Im I

Br
Mike

Comment: Have you tried to return false?

Comment: Yes, and sadly that don't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `beforefeatureremoved` and `beforefeaturesremoved` events will not prevent features from being removed when returning false from a listener - although the name would suggest such behavior.

Comment: Hi ahocevar

Since you help me solve the main issue it dont need to abort the event any longer. But perhaps that will be needed in a later scenario.

Do you have any idea on how to do it? As you write, returning false won't help.

Comment: Better add your features to the layer and use a filter to not display them. But it depends on your use case whether this is feasible or not.

Comment: Sadly thats not possible in this case.